# UNION operator in Ebean (or valid alternatives)

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, playframework, ebean

In a Play project, I have two kinds of entities, `A` and `B`, and two relations, `X` and `Y`. `X` holds couples of `A` entities and a `country` field, while `Y` holds mixed `A-B` couples. The entity `B` holds too a `country` field. I need to make a query on `A`, which tells me if an `A` is the second entity in a relation `X` with `X.country='US'` or in a `Y` relation with `Y.B.country='US'`. A working PostgreSQL statement for this query is:

```
 SELECT * FROM A WHERE A.id IN 
  (
   (SELECT X.a2_id FROM X WHERE country = 'US')
    UNION 
   (SELECT Y.a_id FROM Y WHERE b_id IN
    (SELECT B.id FROM B WHERE B.country = 'US')
   )
  );
```

With Ebean I managed to have each of the subqueries working, just I miss the `union` statement:

```
 Query subqueryX = X.find.select("a2.id")
        .where().eq("country","US").query();

 Query subqueryY = Y.find.select("a.id")
        .where().eq("b.country", "US").query();

 List<A> result = A.find.where().in("id", subquery).findList();
```

Here, `find` is `play.db.ebean.Model.Finder<Id.class, Entity.class>`, like in the computer DB template of Play. I would like to combine the two subqueries in a unique one to put it in the `subquery` parameter of the `result` line.

I've already tried to collect the `id`s from both the `subqueryX` and `subqueryY`, and then using the `ExpressionList<T>.in(String propertyName, Collection<?> values)`, but then I got a `java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed!` if the `Collection` becomes too big (and it is usually the case).

Any suggestion?

**EDIT**

Wait, also the

```
    List<A> result = A.find.where().in("id", subquery).findList();
```

is failing, giving me a `java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed!`. So the question is turned on *how I implement the SQL query above in ebean?*

P.S. The connection closes when in the collection in the `.in()` method are around 32750 ids...

Comment: I managed to have it working directly executing a `RawSql`, but the query produced returns a completely wrong `findRowCount()`... Is this a bug or I am missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two solutions here:

1. Use [RawSql](http://www.avaje.org/ebean/introquery_rawsql.html) to execute your SQL query.
2. You have set of ids and you want a list of objects but calling .in() throws exception when collection is too big. So you can split set of ids to smaller sets and call .in() for every set. Then join result lists into one list.